# Access HEIC and DNG pictures from iOS 11 camera roll

Tags: ios, swift

I'm in throubles accessing original HEIC and DNG files from my iOS 11 app, written in Swift; following the Apple developer's documentation, to access original files it's enought to set `imagePicker.imageExportPreset = UIImagePickerController.ImageURLExportPreset.current` but on the `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL` I still get an URL pointing to a JPEG file; I know the choosen pictures are HEIC and DNG because exporting as original on Mac photo app I get the original file format.

This is the complete code I use:

```
@IBAction func openRoll(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.imageExportPreset = .current
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And on delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

    let path = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as! NSURL
    NSLog("URL: \(path.absoluteString)")
    NSLog("Export: \(picker.imageExportPreset.rawValue)")
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    // ...code to use the image!
}
```

Thank you very much for help, suggestions and working snippets.